# perl regrex that captures substring between tic marks

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to find a solution in perl that captures the filename in the following string -- between the tic marks.

```
my $str = "Saving to: ‘wapenc?T=mavodi-7-13b-2b-3-96-1e3431a’";

(my $results) = $str =~ /‘(.*?[^\\])‘/;
print $results if $results;
```

I need to end up with wapenc?T=mavodi-7-13b-2b-3-96-1e3431a

Comment: Have you noticed, that `‘` isn't equal to `’`, at least in your post?

Comment: Be sure to `use utf8;` in your script, and if your string comes from somewhere else make sure it has been decoded from whatever encoding it comes in (commonly UTF-8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tic characters aren't in the 7-bit ASCII character set, so there is a whole character-encoding rabbit hole to go down here. But the quick and dirty solution is to capture everything in between extended characters.

```
($result) = $str =~ /[^\0-\x7f]+(.*?)[^\0-\x7f]/;
```

`[^\0-\x7f]` matches characters with character values not between 0 and 127, i.e., anything that is not a 7-bit ASCII character including new lines, tabs, and other control sequences. This regular expression will work whether your input is UTF-8 encoded or has already been decoded, and may work for other character encodings, too.

Comment: This won't work (at least, it won't be pretty) if the input is UTF-8 encoded, because UTF-8 encoding contains bytes in the ASCII range.

Comment: Extended characters in UTF-8 avoid 7-bit ASCII

Answer (score 3):

The final tick seems to be different in your regex than in the input string - char 8217 (RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK U+2019) versus 8216 (LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK U+2018). Also, when using Unicode characters in the source, be sure to include

```
use utf8;
```

and save the file UTF-8 encoded.

After fixing these two issues, the code worked for me:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use utf8;

my $str = "Saving to: ‘wapenc?T=mavodi-7-13b-2b-3-96-1e3431a’";

(my $results) = $str =~ /‘(.*?[^\\])’/;
print $results if $results;
```

Comment: After the fixes it worked for me as well. Thank you.